# How to get text right above select box?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I had to change some information up on a working site and now I can't seem to find out what I did wrong.

I have a simple jQuery script that is suppose to take the price(data-price) and calculate the options they select. That works fine; however it's suppose to take the text information right above it and add it to the summary after they choose their options as a summary.

I am not very good with jquery and I tried putting this up as a fiddle but for whatever reason I couldn't get it to work at all so hope this will suffice.

**jquery**

```
var $selections = $('#selections');
var $selects = $("select").change(function () {
    var total = 0;
    $selections.empty();
    $selects.each(function () {
        var $selected = $(this).find("option:selected");
        var price = parseFloat($selected.data("price")) || 0;
        total += price;
        if($selected.val() !== ''){
            $('<li />', {
                text: $selected.text() + $(this).parent().clone().children().remove().end().text()+" " + $selected.data("price")
            }).appendTo($selections)
        }
    })
    $(".summary").text('Est. Total $' + total);
})
```

**HTML**

```
Areas - Selected:<br />
<select name="rooms" id="Areas"> 
         <option value="">Select Rooms..</option>                           
         <option data-price="5" value='1'>10</option>
 </select>

<h3 class="summary" data-price="0">Est. Total $0</h3>
   <div class="well">
        <h4>Breakdown:</h4>
         <ul id="selections"></ul>
</div>
```

**The output would look like:**

```
10 Area - selected: 5
```

**Now it looks like**

```
10 5
```

So the text right above the select box is not being selected. I know it's in this code here:

```
text: $selected.text() + $(this).parent().clone().children().remove().end().text()+" " + $selected.data("price")
```

I just don't really understand what it's doing and how when I removed div's from legacy code would effect it.

**[EDIT]**

I found out it's not working due to adding Selectric.js to my drop-downs. here is what the output is now.

```
        <div class="selectricWrapper"><div class="selectricHideSelect"><select id="Areas" name="rooms"> 
    <option value="">Select Areas</option>                                                      <option value="1" data-price="8.95">1</option>
        <option  value="2"dataprice="17.90">2</option>                                <option value="3" data-price="26.85">3</option>
            <option value="4" data-price="35.80">4</option>                             <option value="5" data-price="39.95">5</option>
<option value="6" data-price="53.70">6</option>
<option value="7" data-price="69.95">8</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="selectric">
        <p class="label">3</p><b class="button">▾</b>
        </div>
        <div class="selectricItems" style="width: 298px; display: none;">
        <ul>
        <li class="">Select Areas..</li>
        <li class="">1</li>
        <li class="">2</li>
        <li class="selected">3</li>
        <li class="">4</li>
        <li class="">5</li><li class="">6</li>
        <li class="last">8</li>
        </ul>
        </div>

    </div>
```

How could I change my jquery up to account for the selectric.js?

Comment: Is this what you want? http://jsfiddle.net/JB8KJ/1/

Comment: I have to admit your question is very good and detailed.

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I want it to do. But for some reason it doesn't work on my development.

Comment: Thank you Aaron. I am trying lol

Comment: What do you mean with " it doesn't work on my development. " ?

Comment: It works how I mentioned in my question it won't select the text right above. But i found out why. I added selectric.js to the select drop-downs and didn't realize how drastically it changes the drop-downs. If I take them out they work but they select ALL the drop-downs I have. I am going to update my question to include the selectric code.

Comment: @repeater09 answer your own question with the revised code

Comment: huh? My question isn't answered.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by removing Selectric.js and by adding div's before each select option